# how to write a function that uses broom, dplyr and lm?

Tags: r, dplyr, broom

Consider this very simple example

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

dataframe <- data_frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                        group = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                        value = c(200,400,120,300,100,100))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
     id group value
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1   200
2     2     1   400
3     3     1   120
4     4     2   300
5     5     2   100
6     6     2   100
```

Here I want to write a function that outputs the upper bound of the confidence estimate for the mean of `value`. That is,

```
get_ci_high <- function(data, myvar){
  confint_tidy(lm(data = data, myvar ~ 1)) %>% pull(conf.high)
}
```

Now, this works easily

```
confint_tidy(lm(data = dataframe, value ~ 1)) %>% pull(conf.high)
[1] 332.9999
```

This works as well (note the call after a `group_by`)

```
dataframe %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(dealwithit = get_ci_high(., value))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   group [2]
     id group value dealwithit
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1     1   200   598.2674
2     2     1   400   598.2674
3     3     1   120   598.2674
4     4     2   300   453.5102
5     5     2   100   453.5102
6     6     2   100   453.5102
```

This works wonderfully

```
mindblow <- function(data, groupvar, outputvar){
  quo_groupvar <- enquo(groupvar)
  quo_outputvar <- enquo(outputvar)

  data %>% group_by(!!quo_groupvar) %>% 
    summarize(output =  get_ci_high(., !!quo_outputvar))%>% 
    ungroup()

}

> mindblow(dataframe, groupvar = group, outputvar = value)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  group   output
  <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1 598.2674
2     2 453.5102
```

... but this **FAILS**

```
get_ci_high(dataframe, value)
 Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'value' not found
```

I dont get what is wrong here. I really need a solution that works in the four cases above.

Any ideas?
Many thanks!!

Comment: Try `get_ci_high(dataframe, dataframe$value)`.

Comment: @meenaparam That wouldn't work because it wouldn't respect the `group_by`

Comment: @DavidRobinson What `group_by` parameter?

Comment: @DavidRobinson @meenaparam there is no `group_by` indeed. But I plan to use this function in a groupby if that matters. However, the setting is simpler here

Comment: @meenaparam Oops, my mistake. That would work in this case; but I figured the asker is looking for something that could work with a `group_by` afterwards, since they need it in a formula

Comment: @DavidRobinson that's correct. let me edit the question for clarity

Comment: Aha, that makes sense, thanks for editing the Q. @DavidRobinson has beaten me to an answer, nice solution and explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that when you pass the `value` argument, you want R to use its *name* `"value"` in the formula, rather than the value of the variable (which doesn't exist).

One solution would be to extract the name using `substitute()` ([non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html)), and create a formula using `as.formula`:

```
get_ci_high <- function(data, myvar) {
  col_name <- as.character(substitute(myvar))
  fmla <- as.formula(paste(col_name, "~ 1"))

  confint_tidy(lm(data = data, fmla)) %>% pull(conf.high)
}

get_ci_high(dataframe, value)
```

However, I'd strongly recommend passing the *formula* `value ~ 1` as the second argument instead. This is both simpler and more flexible for performing other linear models (when you have predictors as well).

```
get_ci_high <- function(data, fmla) {      
  confint_tidy(lm(data = data, fmla)) %>% pull(conf.high)
}

get_ci_high(dataframe, value ~ 1)
```

Comment: super nice, thanks David. Just to be sure, a formula is something R interpret differently than a string or a variable, right? this is why it is working here?

Comment: @ᴺᴼᴼᴮᴵᴱ Yes exactly; R keeps a formula intact, and can later pass it to other functions, without needing the variables within it to exist immediately (e.g. try out `a ~ b`).

Comment: argh... Problem is, your nice first solution does not work in a more general setting. Consider this function `mindblow <- function(data, groupvar, outputvar){
  quo_groupvar <- enquo(groupvar)
  quo_outputvar <- enquo(outputvar)
  
  df_agg <- data %>% group_by( !!quo_groupvar) %>% 
    summarize(output = get_ci_high(., !!quo_outputvar))
  
}` Do you see an easy fix here?

Comment: question edited for clarity. I think an easy fix is to write two versions of the same function. but that looks sooooo inefficient

Comment: OK, made it to work with some crazy R magic. use`get_ci_high(.,!!rlang::get_expr(quo_outputvar)))` in the `mindblow` function. I am not sure WHY this works tho :)

Comment: HA! actually it does not work because the regressions are not computed by groups... I think this is worth another question